# Coffeescript - call a function from a string, javascript code does not work

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

So in javascript I would dynamically call a function from a string like this:

```
window["function_name"](args);
```

However if I try this in coffeescript it does not work, is this something to do with the way coffee script does not have a function in the global namespace?

All of the functions are wrapped in a function like this:

```
(function() {
#code here
}).call(this);
```

So how do I call a function from a string in coffeescript?

Comment: It depends on where/how the function is defined. You can always write `@someFn = () ->...` and in another file `@['someFn']()`. But if your talking about one in the current file, you'll have to make it an object method, either of `window` as I did or some other object.

Answer (score 2):

I tried [here](http://coffeescript.org/) ("Try Coffescript" section) this (sorry about identation):

```
  ( ->
    foo = () ->
     alert "it works" ;
  ).call(this); #IFFE on Coffescript

  window["foo"]() ;
```

And it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
window["function_name"](args);
```

This code in CoffeeScript compiles to:

```
window["function_name"](args);
```

in javscript.

So the problem is not CoffeeScript, but your code.